# Getting task timeout error when accessing the django application which is deployed on AWS

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, zappa

I have my django application deployed on AWS. It is working fine as of now but when i tried to hit an url which is deployed on ec2 instance it is showing task time out error.is there any way to overcome it.

```
[1556766665330] [DEBUG] 2018-12-14T05:46:25.330Z 98072431-ff63-11e8-97db- 
 2d7bd216d81f Starting new HTTP connection (1): 1.2.3.4:3000

[1544799995279] 2018-12-14T05:46:55.279Z 98072431-ff63-11e8-97db-2d7bd216d81f 
 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

my django application is deployed on aws through zappa

Comment: did you check security groups?

Comment: @BanjoObayomi yes, i had security groups set up in zappa_settings.json as "vpc_config" : {
        "SubnetIds": [ "subnet-65xxxxxx","subnet-6cxxxxxx" ], 
        "SecurityGroupIds": [ "sg-012e8860cxxxxxxxx" ]
    }

Answer (score 0):

Default zappa configuration is a timeout after 30 seconds.  See [documentation for zappa_settings.json](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa).

This is the default because API Gateway timeout is 30 seconds (https://seancoates.com/blogs/api-gateway-timeout-workaround/)